# Python installing whirlpool without C++ BuildTools

Tags: python, pip, whirlpool

I'm trying to install whirlpool package with pip but it gives `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required` error
I tried `pip install whirlpool --only-binary=:all:` but gives same error.
I also searched for whirlpool unofficial binary file but I don't find anything
Can I install it without installing c++ build tools? because I haven't enough size for that.

**Python** 3.8.3 - **Pip** 20.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheels on `pypi` for `whirlpool` only go up to python 3.6, so you will either have to downgrade your python version or make some space on your hard drive

Comment: Downgrading to 3.6 fixed my problem. Thanks.